# Create an xml file in android & later read from that file

Tags: android

Friends I want to create a xml file in my android app where I want to store a variable for image(later on I would fetch that image from resources),date,time & number. All these things would be cuimg at run time. So I am finding it difficult to save them in form of xml file.Also I wish to read info from this fila back again. Please help me with the same.

Friends I got solution from `http://www.anddev.org/write_a_simple_xml_file_in_the_sd_card_using_xmlserializer-t8350.html` but now I am facing the issue is that only the latest values are over written with the last values(I have tested it by using date feature)
Please help me for the same

Comment: You may use `DOM` or `SAX` API to create and parse the XML document.

Comment: @AVD can you share with me any tutorial/code for reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `DOM` or `SAX` API to create and parse the XML document.

DOM sample to create XML document:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory=null;
 DocumentBuilder builder=null;
 try {
    //1
    factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    //2
    Document document=builder.newDocument();

    //3
    document.setXmlVersion("1.0");

    //4
    Node root=document.createElement("Students");


    Element student=document.createElement("Student");
    student.setAttribute("class", "1");
    Element roll=document.createElement("Roll");
    Element name=document.createElement("Name");

    roll.appendChild(document.createTextNode("10"));
    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Mr.X"));

    student.appendChild(roll);
    student.appendChild(name);

    root.appendChild(student);

    document.appendChild(root);

       //5
    TransformerFactory transFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans=transFactory.newTransformer();

    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "5");

    trans.transform(new DOMSource(document),new StreamResult("file.xml"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

To read/parse XML document:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory=null;
   DocumentBuilder builder=null;
   Document doc=null;

   try {
    factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    doc=builder.parse("file.xml");

    Element  root=doc.getDocumentElement(); //root

    NodeList list=root.getChildNodes();

    for(int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
    Node node=list.item(i);
    switch(node.getNodeType()){
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                  System.out.println("Text Node"); break;
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
                  System.out.println("Element Node");
                  NodeList student=node.getChildNodes();
                  if(node.hasAttributes()){
                      System.out.println(node.getAttributes()
                                 .getNamedItem("class").getTextContent());
              }
             for(int j=0;j<student.getLength();j++){
                  Node nd=student.item(j);
                          if(nd.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                            System.out.println(nd.getNodeName() + " " 
                                         + nd.getTextContent());
                            }
             }
             break;
        default:
              System.out.println("Other node");
              break;
           }
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
```